Patching Lookup column
I have two tables students and subjects. Subject contains subject_id (pk) and subject_name. Student table contains subject_id which is a lookup column to Subject table. Student table does not contains subject_name (but it is inside lookup column).
I have bulit a gallery with Student table and it is filtered using a dropdown whose items are subject_name from Subject table.
On the click of new button, an item needs to be added to the gallery, for which I now uses patch. Since I am filtering on the value of Student table, I am not able to create a new record in Student table with the subject_id as lookup field.
How can I add a new entry to the Student table with the related lookup value(subject_id) for the subject_name selected in the dropdown?
